# Awk a external Command and Get line

Tags: awk, cmd, getline

I am trying to see whats the best way to extract the 3rd line from this command but i can't seem to get it

```
awk 'BEGIN{while("service ipsec status" | getline x) print  x}'
```

Comment: awk is a tool for parsing text, it is not an environment from which to call external tools. That would be a shell. Using getline is rarely the right approach, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: fedorqui: `awk 'NR==3{print}'` you mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
service ipsec status | awk 'NR==3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
service ipsec status | sed '3!d'
```